# Export Telerik RadGridView to specific sheet

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

How I can export a table to a specific Excel sheet ?

```
string file = this.radGridView.ToExcelML(objects, true);
File.WriteAllText("F:\\test.xls", file);
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question.  What have you tried?  You posted one line of code, but nothing more about it.  Why shouldn't I conclude that line works and you are done?   That is, if you tried that approach and it didn't work, include the error.

Comment: Sorry, the export works correctly. But I generates a file in a default sheet "WorkSheet" I would like to indicate the name of the sheet in the export.